# how to programmatically export all azure databricks notebooks out of a workspace

Tags: azure-databricks

I am implementing a lifecycle management plan of Azure Databricks notebooks for my organization.  One part of this management plan is to programmatically identify and deprecate "stale" notebooks out of a particular workspace (e.g., notebooks that haven't been ran in x days).  To identify stale notebooks manually, I do three things -- (1) export all notebooks out of Azure Databricks, (2) export all notebook runs out of Log Analytics (via the DatabricksJobs table), and (3) compare (1) and (2).  I want to automate this and feed it into an Excel file or Power BI dashboard.

I know how to automate (2).  Is it possible to automate (1)?  If so, how?

Comment: You can use databricks cli or api to automate the export of notebooks

Comment: Through the CLI or API, is it possible to get just a list of notebooks?

Comment: yes , you can use workspace CLI .. please refer this https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/workspace-cli.html#list-objects-in-a-workspace